# Simple Celsius to Fahrenheit not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and was making a simple JavaScript app that converts an entered Celsius value and outputs Fahrenheit. It doesn't seem to work tho, what am I doing wrong.

```js
  
     function CelciusToFarenheit() {
      a = document.getElementById("Celcius").value;
      b = document.getElementById("Farenheit");
      f = (a * (9/5) + 32);
      b.innerHTML = f;
      }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Projects</title>
    <script src="pr.js" type="text/js"></script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="div1">
      Convert celcius to farenheit:
      <br>
      <br>
      Celcius: <input type="number" name="Celcius" id="Celcius"><br>
      Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span><br>
      <button id="submit" onclick="CelciusToFarenheit()">Calculate</button>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your Celsius `input` has a `name` property, but not an `id` property. Replace `name` with `id` in your HTML. Also please use proper variable declaration syntax (`var`, `let` or `const`) when declaring variables.

Comment: There is a W3School tutorial on this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_celsius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change name or add `id=Celcius` to input

```js
function CelciusToFarenheit() {
  a = document.getElementById("Celcius").value;
  b = document.getElementById("Farenheit");
  f = (a * (9 / 5) + 32);
  b.innerHTML = f;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Projects</title>
  <script src="pr.js" type="text/js"></script>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    Convert celcius to farenheit:
    <br>
    <br> Celcius: <input type="number" id="Celcius"><br> Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span><br>
    <button id="submit" onclick="CelciusToFarenheit()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work when I put the code in TryItEditor, but not on my atom.ide.
I linked my js correctly using correct names.

Answer (score 0):

You have not placed **Celcius** as an **ID** but as a **name** in your HTML code.

Do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Projects</title>
   <script src="pr.js" type="text/js"></script>
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="div1">
      Convert celcius to farenheit:
      <br>
      <br>
      Celcius: <input type="number" id="Celcius" name="Celcius"><br>
      Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span><br>
      <button id="submit" onclick="CelciusToFarenheit()">Calculate</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I recommend you use a tag like `<p>` or `div` instead of `<br>` before and after some code. Like in this situation.

```
<br>Celcius: <input type="number" id="Celcius" name="Celcius"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared only name not id in your input field. Write id

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Projects</title>
      <script src="pr.js" type="text/js"></script>
     <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="div1">
        Convert celcius to farenheit:
         <br>
       <br>
      Celcius: <input type="number" name="Celcius" id="Celcius"><br>
      Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span><br>
      <button id="submit" onclick="CelciusToFarenheit()">Calculate</button>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
function CelciusToFarenheit() {
          a = document.getElementById("Celcius").value;
          b = document.getElementById("Farenheit");
          f = (a * (9 / 5) + 32);
          b.innerHTML = f;
  }
```

your script unchange